# Simultaneous div show/hide and enable/disable on checkbox check/uncheck using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have the following view:

```
<div>
    <label id = "show_hide_checkbox_label">Text Input?</label>
    <input type ="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" onchange="show_hide_divs()" />
</div>
<div id="text_div" hidden>
    <label id ="emp_id_input_label">Employee ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="emp_id" id="employee_id_input"></input>
</div>
<div id="select_div">
     <label id= "emp_id_add_label">Employee ID:</label>
     <select name="emp_id" id = "employee_id">
     <option>--Select--</option>
     <option>INCB001</option>
     <option>INCB002</option>
     <option>INCB003</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

What I want to do is this:

By default, the checkbox is unchecked, the textbox is hidden and disabled and the select element is visible, and I can only post data from the options in the select element, I can not post data from textbox. But if I check the checkbox, then select element becomes hidden and disabled, and the textbox is visible and enabled, and I can only post data from textbox and not from the select element. If I uncheck the checkbox again, the behavior is reversed and so on.

Unfortunately, the jQuery code I have below doesn't allow me to disable/enable and show/hide the divs properly on checkbox change.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
    <script>
        function show_hide_divs()
        {
                if ($('.myCheckbox').is(':checked'))
                {
                    $("div#text_div").show();
                    $("div#text_div").children().prop('disabled', 'false');
                    $("div#select_div").hide();
                    $("div#select_div").children().prop('disabled', 'true');
                }
                else {
                     $("div#select_div").show();
                     $("div#select_div").children().prop('disabled', 'false');
                     $("div#text_div").hide();
                     $("div#text_div").children().prop('disabled', 'true');
                }
        }
    </script>
```

It seems there's something wrong with my jQuery code, only just I can't figure out myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are your current code is in a DOM ready handler so the function is effectively hidden in the scope of the wrapper function.

Don't use attribute-based event handlers with jQuery. There is no point separating the event registration from the event handler code, when the jQuery version is more flexible (supports multiple handlers).

Also, use boolean values for boolean prop settings. Seems to be a bug in some browsers if you use strings:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3me1og4o/2/

```
$(function () {
    $('.myCheckbox').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("div#text_div").show();
            $("div#text_div").children().prop('disabled', false);
            $("div#select_div").hide();
            $("div#select_div").children().prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $("div#select_div").show();
            $("div#select_div").children().prop('disabled', false);
            $("div#text_div").hide();
            $("div#text_div").children().prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

It also means you can reference the `checkbox` clicked as `this` in the handler, which is also better as it leads to supporting multiple controls on the same page (you would then start making the other selectors relative to the clicked control).

Note: `$(function(){}):` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: So you suggest I should get rid of this: onchange="show_hide_divs()" inside my checkbox?

Comment: Yes. indeed... You should find the example easier to maintain as the handler registration and handler are together.

Comment: It's still not working. When checkbox is checked, `text_div` is visible and enabled, but `select_div` is still visible and enabled.  I want the entire `select_div` disabled and hidden on checkbox change.

Comment: According to Chrome's DOM inspector the select is disabled and invisible. What are you using to confirm this?

Comment: I'm using Mozilla Firefox v.33.0.2

Comment: Ah.. Use boolean `true` and `false` with prop (not strings). That should work on all browsers. I will adjust.

Comment: both Vinita's and your answer have the exact same problem. The divs are permanently disabled. The divs are supposed to be enabled onchange alternatively.

Comment: @Crescent Moon: Already fixed. It was due to using bool values as strings with `prop`. Need to use boolean values.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot to refresh my browser. Yup!!! It's working now. Thanks a lot TrueBlueAussie and Vinita. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/9cdoz896/2/

**JS**

```
$('.myCheckbox').on('click',function(){
 if ($('.myCheckbox').is(':checked'))
            {
                $("div#text_div").show();
                $("div#text_div").children().prop('disabled', false);
                $("div#select_div").hide();
                $("div#select_div").children().prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                 $("div#select_div").show();
                 $("div#select_div").children().prop('disabled', false);
                 $("div#text_div").hide();
                 $("div#text_div").children().prop('disabled', true);
            }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
#text_div{
        display:none;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label id = "show_hide_checkbox_label">Text Input?</label>
    <input type ="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" />
</div>
<div id="text_div" >
    <label id ="emp_id_input_label">Employee ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="emp_id" id="employee_id_input"></input>
</div>
<div id="select_div">
     <label id= "emp_id_add_label">Employee ID:</label>
     <select name="emp_id" id = "employee_id">
     <option>--Select--</option>
     <option>INCB001</option>
     <option>INCB002</option>
     <option>INCB003</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems both @TrueBlueAussies and your answer have the exact same problem. The divs are permanently disabled. The divs are supposed to be enabled onchange alternatively.

Comment: `select` is not enabled when I uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: Best you edit your answer to match your new JSFiddle, as the answer you posted *is not correct* (but your new JSFiddle is).

Comment: And the JSFiddle link... :)

Comment: Note: for a `checkbox`, you should listen for `change` and not `click` as some browsers will report the previous `checked` value.

Answer (score 0):

Is the script tag included in your html itself? or `show_hide_divs` function visible to DOM(i.e. handler is registered after DOM is loaded). If script is in same html then move script tag to end of body tag.  If its in external file then remove `<script>` tag first.
Don't use inline event handler.
Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrk_m/g9Lo3u8r/1/
This fiddle also solves your problem of disabling elements permanently. It uses removeProp and addProp.

Comment: The script is inside my html file.

Comment: This would have been better with an explanation of your use of `removeProp` and `addProp`, *which fixed the actual problem*, rather than just focus on `window.onload` (which, in a jQuery question, is not as good/flexible as using a DOM ready handler). :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie agreed with your points of both avoiding inline method handler & focusing on addProp and removeProp. But then I was trying to ask Crescent Moon whether event handler is getting registered first.

Comment: Ask questions in comments. I can only go by the answer you have posted (which would have broken it further if they followed your advice to wrap it in a `onload` function). Just edit your answer to focus on the real problem (which you also solved) :)

Comment: Note: It *does not* matter that the function is registered later for inline function calls, as that is evaluated at event time. It can be anywhere in the page for this example.

Comment: Edited the answer. @TrueBlueAussie Yes, inline event handler will need function out of scope of DOMready event.